# Handling sample identity in aggregated 10x libraries?

Tags: rna-seq, r, scrnaseq, 10x-genomics

`cellranger aggr` can combine multiple libraries (samples), and appends each barcode with an integer (e.g. AGACCATTGAGACTTA-1). The sample identity is not recorded in the combined `matrix.mtx` file.

https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/using/aggregate#gem_groups

How can we keep and assign sample information to each cell after loading the data into `R`? (e.g. `Seurat::Read10X()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### An example solution for Seurat:

Retrieve sample IDs from the .csv used with `cellranger`:

```
samples <- read.csv(file.path("/path/to/csv", "nameof.csv"), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Load the 10x dataset and initialize the Seurat object:

```
cells.data <- Read10X("path/to/filtered_gene_bc_matrices")

cells <- new("seurat", raw.data=cells.data)
```

Get barcodes and suffix:

```
cellcodes <- as.data.frame(cells@raw.data@Dimnames[[2]])
colnames(cellcodes) <- "barcodes"
rownames(cellcodes) <- cellcodes$barcodes

cellcodes$libcodes <- as.factor(gsub(pattern=".+-", replacement="", cellcodes$barcodes))
cellcodes$samples <- as.vector(samples$library_id[cellcodes$libcodes])
```

Create dataframe for `meta.data` argument and set up object:

```
sampleidentity <- cellcodes["samples"]

cells <- Setup(cells,
               meta.data=sampleidentity,
               min.cells=3,
               min.genes=200,
               do.logNormalize=T, total.expr=1e4, project="projectname")
```

Use the `group.by` argument of various functions.

Comment: The new Seurat 2.0 has the `MergeSeurat()` and `AddSamples()` functions. See [this question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/cellranger-aggr-and-seurat-merge-difference) and [seurat vignette](http://satijalab.org/seurat/merge_vignette.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep track of the file order you used for `aggr`.  The suffix number represents which represents the aggregated sample. You could store this information in a text file and load it into R independently of the `Read10X` function and combine it with the cell names to get their sample names. From the page you [link](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/using/aggregate#gem_groups):

> Gem Groups
>
> This is an integer that is appended to each barcode in the
>   gene-barcode matrix. For example, *AGACCATTGAGACTTA-1* and
>   *AGACCATTGAGACTTA-2* are distinct cell barcodes from different
>   libraries, despite having the same nucleotide sequence.
>
> The numbering of the GEM groups will reflect the order that the
>   libraries were provided in the [Aggregation CSV](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/using/aggregate#csv_setup).